# wireguard error message: resolvconf: command not found

Tags: wireguard

Ubuntu newbie here, with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

My employer uses Wireguard and they sent me the .conf file. The file name is sp.conf, and they clearly told me not to modify it at all. This means I can skip the server configuration.

So I installed it on my Ubuntu pc:

```
sudo apt-get install wireguard
```

The sp.conf is in my home directory, so I ran this:

```
sudo wg-quick up sp
```

And it returned:

```
[#] ip link add sp type wireguard
[#] wg setconf sp /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.140.0.11/32 dev sp
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev sp
[#] resolvconf -a sp -m 0 -x
/usr/bin/wg-quick: line 32: resolvconf: command not found
[#] ip link delete dev sp
```

I'm completely lost here. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** While I can't duplicate this issue, there's an offsite discussion that came up in a quick web search: https://superuser.com/q/1500691. In short, you'll need to modify your WG install process to take `systemd` functionality into account.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like resolvconf command is missing in your system or it isn't installed, try this:

```
sudo apt install openresolv
```

I found this solution on https://superuser.com/questions/1500691/usr-bin-wg-quick-line-31-resolvconf-command-not-found-wireguard-debian

Answer (score 0):

Check out

https://github.com/runfalk/synology-wireguard/issues/56

I removed the DNS line in my *.conf file with a simple text editor and it works like a charm.

P. S. Backup the original *.conf in a safe place before trying this.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@armbian:/etc/wireguard# resolvconf
Command 'resolvconf' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install systemd-resolved
root@armbian:/etc/wireguard# apt install systemd-resolved

...succeed

root@armbian:/etc/wireguard# systemctl start wg-quick@wg0
```

work for me